# How to count a value from a cell which contains multiple values?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a table with cells which contain comma-separated multiple values as follows:

```
+----------+
| Column A |
|----------|
| a, b     |
|----------|
| a, b, d  |
|----------|
| b, c     |
|----------|
| c, d, e  |
+----------+
```

I would like to get a table which counts the number of `a`, `b`, `...`, `e` as follows:

```
 +-----------------------+
 | Column A  | Column B  |
 |-----------------------|
 |     a     |     2     |
 |-----------------------|
 |     b     |     3     |
 |-----------------------|
 |     c     |     2     |
 |-----------------------|
 |     d     |     2     |
 |-----------------------|
 |     e     |     1     |
 +-----------------------+
```

Is there any Google Sheets or LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet formula to do this?

Comment: `COUNT` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **C1:** `=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ,",1,A:A)," ,")))`
- **D1:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C:C),COUNTIF(A:A,"=*"&C:C&"*"),))`

  [image]

Comment: It works and it is what I need. (Other two answers also work.)

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ,",1,A:A)," ,")),
 "select Col1, count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1) ''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
={UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ,",1,A:A)," ,"))),
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ,",1,A:A)," ,")))),
 COUNTIF(A:A,"=*"&UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ,",1,A:A)," ,")))&"*"),))}
```

[image: 3]